# Using arguments in the replacement text of an alias

Tags: bash, alias

The bash manual says for alias,

> There is no mechanism for using arguments in the replacement text, as
>   in csh. If arguments are needed, a shell function should be used (see
>   Section 3.3 [Shell Functions], page 17).

What do the two sentences mean?

"using arguments in the replacement text" doesn't seem to mean the following, which succeeds

```
$ alias foo="echo bac" 
$ foo
bac
$ foo hello
bac hello
```

Comment: That's not using an argument. The macro was simply replaced with the expansion, and the argument is still there after it. But there's no way to substitute an argument into the middle of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the wording is not perfect, unless you take it *very* literally. Bash does not replace any *aliased* text with arguments; it will *append* arguments to the text, as you saw. This is in contrast with [CSH aliases](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-101) which expands arguments *inside* the replacement text.

The second sentence, IMHO, stems from the above restriction, and encourages the more-flexible function definitions over the simplistic aliases.